# How do I filter array of objects based on a list of possible ID properties?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter `arr2`. If the element doesn't have an ID listed in `arr`, then I want it to be removed. How could I make this happen in javascript?

```
var arr= ["a", "b", "d"]
var arr2=[{id:"a", value:1},{id:"b", value:2}, {id:"c", value:3}]
```

```
result:
[{id:"a", value:1},{id:"b", value:2}]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and in the callback function check if `arr` `includes` the `id` of the object under iteration. If so then add the elements in the accumulator array

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "d"]
var arr2 = [{
  id: "a",
  value: 1
}, {
  id: "b",
  value: 2
}, {
  id: "c",
  value: 3
}];

const newData = arr2.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (arr.includes(curr.id)) {

    acc.push(curr)
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

if arr items are always strings you can do this:

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "d"];
var arr2 = [{id:"a", value:1},{id:"b", value:2}, {id:"c", value:3}];

let str = arr.join('')
let filtered = arr2.filter(x => str.includes(x.id));
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

```
var arr= ["a", "b", "d"]
var arr2=[{id:"a", value:1},{id:"b", value:2}, {id:"c", value:3}]

const filteredArray = arr2.filter(obj => {
  return arr.includes(obj.id)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using filter, reduce, and includes are all nearly twice as slow as simply using a loop. To walk you through it, all it does is check over every element in the second array and check to see if it's id property is in the first array, and if it is, it clones it. Also, for future reference, that title is written poorly. A much better title would be "How to filter array of objects based on a list of possible ID properties"

```js
var arr= ["a", "b", "d"]
var arr2=[{id:"a", value:1},{id:"b", value:2}, {id:"c", value:3}]
let clone = []
for(let i = 0;i < arr2.length;i++){
    for(let j = 0;j < arr.length; j++) if(arr2[i].id === arr[j]) clone.push(arr2[j])
}
console.log(clone)
```